# How to access private static field at initialization of other private static field

Tags: php

Let's say that I have a static field `$b` that relies on the value of another previously defined static field `$a`. When I do this ...

```
class Foo {
    private static $a = "Hello";
    private static $b = self::$a . " World"; // Error

    ...
}
```

... it gives me a syntax error. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you happy and you know it: syntax error!

Comment: It would be great if stuff like this would be documented somewhere.

Comment: Not that I know of. This isn't possible using class constants either.

Comment: It's just philosophical question or you really want to use it somewhere? If yes - can you do a case study for us where you need such solution?

Comment: @speccode: It's just a theoretical (and apparently stupid) question, thanks for your help.

Comment: @subarachnid Theoretically - such situation shouldn't never happen. As you're defining variables "manually" you will replace `self::$a` with "Hello". There is no reason for calling other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.php.net/static) explains why this doesn't work:

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.